# Как обновить картинку (captcha), не перезагружая страницу?

Tags: jquery, captcha, php, html, javascript

Капча создается **php**-скриптом, напр., `<img src='captcha.php'>`. Так вот если юзер 1 раз ввел правильный код с капчи, то по логике вещей то действие, на которое форма подвешена, должно произойти и форма должна обновится - все это, не перезагружая страницу, должно происходить, ну с полями все просто: их можно легко очистить, а как быть с капчей? Я пытался remove'ить ее, а append'ом добавлять форму, пытался src очищать и заново атрибут вписывать, но толку из этого равным счетом - никакого, что с ней делать-то в таком случае?

Comment: Могу предположить, что она просто кешируется. Потому как вариант, имя файла, которое отдает captcha.php можно попробовать делать уникальным.

Comment: интересная идея, я тоже думаю что оно кэшируется, а имени как раз нету у нее. Но попробую сделать ей имя (уникальное), посмотрим что из этого выйдет.

Comment: увы, не прокатило, как была картинка, так и осталась с тем же кодом.

Comment: капча заточена под сессию, удалять сессию тоже не вариант, тогда форма может выполнить только 1 действие, да и капча не обновляется все равно...

Comment: ааа, все разобрался, ни name надо было менять, а вот так напр. :
captcha.php?m=123 на captcha.php?m=321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#img_id').attr('src', 'captcha.php?r=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: я так и сделал, спасибо.